# Who are the Heroes that Sweet Mask acknowledged?

Tags: one-punch-man

I saw an interesting question: [How does Sweet Mask (A-Class rank 1) plan to stop unworthy heroes from moving to S-Class?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/29907/how-does-sweet-mask-a-class-rank-1-plan-to-stop-unworthy-heroes-from-moving-to)

My question is, at the moment, who are the Heroes that Sweet Mask acknowledged as **worthy Heroes**? Are the Heroes he acknowledged all S-Class Heroes only?

Answer (score 4):

Sweet Mask has acknowledged:

- **King** (S-Class) - **Chapter 93**
  *He acknowledges King's split-second decision-making and fearless actions* and even went so far as to say that there are S-class heroes serious about their jobs after all.
- **Feather** (A-Class) - **Chapter 94**
  He says that Feather is *good and that he has star potential*.

So, no, he not only acknowledges S-class heroes but A-class heroes as well.